# Azure dashboard not showing all columns

Tags: azure, sorting, dashboard, portal, customizing

On my dashboard I want to see a list of virtual machines that are deployed in my subscription. To create this I searched for Virtual Machine in the portal and got list of all VMs deployed. Next I added a few additional columns to the list which I needed. I sorted on the VM names. I then pinned the view to the dashboard. However in the dashboard I cannot see the newly added columns nor the sorting. It shows a default view of the VMs. When I click on the "see more" link at the bottom it brings me to original updated VM list search screen which shows the updated columns list. Is there no way to reflect the updated columns, sorting in the dashboard?

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: Nope, still continuing with this 'feature' unless I get a definite solution

Comment: I think there is no way to do it. Even if you remove all the columns, also not change in the dashboard. The most likely way is downloading the .json file of the dashboard and edit it, but per my test, this does not work. I think it is azure built-in setting, only way is giving the feedback mentioned in my reply, may be you could accept it.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it seems  no way to do that, you could only resize it, there will be stable columns regardless of what you updated columns list(if there is not enough size, will not all displayed).

For more details about azure portal dashboard, refer to the links, [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboards) and [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboards-create-programmatically). 
Besides, if you want to improve the dashboard, you could post your idea in the [azure portal feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-portal).